# Variable as the entire Shell command from VBA

Tags: vba, command-line, vbscript

I have a shell command to execute a VBScript, that works when it's all typed in as a string literal:

WORKS:

```
Shell("cscript.exe ""C:\Users\slang\Documents\Folio\test.vbs"" ""C:\Users\slang\Documents\Folio"" ""hbs110.fff"" ")
```

But if I build the string being placed into the shell and have it as a variable, it doesn't:

DOES NOT WORK:

```
strVBSPath = "C:\Users\slang\Documents\Folio\test.vbs"
strParentPath = "C:\Users\slang\Documents\Folio" 
strFFF = "hbs110.fff"
strShellScript = Chr(34) & "cscript.exe " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & strVBSPath & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & strParentPath & _
        Chr(34) & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & strFFF & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34)


Shell (strShellScript)
```

I'm trying to run it from a VBA module. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: sorry, can't recall the exact syntax for VB, but does the equivalent of `print "$strShellScript"` look correct? Good luck.

Comment: @shelter It does. I use debug.print, then copy/paste it as the string literal and it works. It just doesn't want to work as a variable. Maybe it's my environment?

Comment: You seem to be confusing string literals and strings. Your `strShellScript` is a string that contains the string literal inside the working shell command -- but it doesn't contain the string that this string literal represents. If you try `Debug.Print "cscript.exe ""C:\Users\slang\Documents\Folio\test.vbs"" ""C:\Users\slang\Documents\Folio"" ""hbs110.fff"" "` you will see the difference.

Comment: It *is* confusing. Too late to change the design decision now, but things would have been easier if Visual Basic used C-style escapes rather than that double-quoting monstrosity.

Comment: None of your arguments have spaces so you don't even need quotes here...

Comment: This is simply a lack of understanding between defining strings and including string literals, the reason for *doubling the quotes* is to escape the quote and not have VBA see it as start or end of defining a string. When you use `Chr(34)` you are already defining an escaped quote, there is no need to double these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for all that juggling...

```
Dim args
args = Array("cscript.exe", _
             "'C:\Users\slang\Documents\Folio\test.vbs'", _
             "'C:\Users\slang\Documents\Folio'", _
             "hbs110.fff")

Shell Replace(Join(args, " "),"'", """")
```

Comment: A nice compact way of doing it, but it doesn't explain what the OP was doing wrong.

Comment: @Lankymart - I guess I find the OP's approach almost undecipherable: for me there's no *right* way to do it that way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove Chr(34) from the beginning of your string:

from:

```
strShellScript = Chr(34) & "cscript.exe " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & strVBSPath & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & strParentPath & _
        Chr(34) & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & strFFF & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34)
```

to:

```
strShellScript = "cscript.exe " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & strVBSPath & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & strParentPath & _
        Chr(34) & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & strFFF & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34)
```

Comment: Removing the opening Chr(34) and the trailing space and quote worked, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim args
args = Array("cscript.exe", _
             "'" & strVBSPath & "'", _
             "'" & strFFFPath & "'", _
             strFFF)

Shell Replace(Join(args, " "), "'", """")
```

For me is the most readable method.

Comment: This really should be a comment. You are just posting what [has already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59326368/692942).